# how to create a custom dropdown with my own html in the dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I have a textbox and as the user enters into the textbox, I want a dropdown to apppear, but I want to be able to actually inject HTML to the dropdown space... (as I am trying to insert a treeview)

see image attached
[image]

Comment: You can't do that with standard `select` boxes, they're OS controls. Try using the `Select2` plugin.

Comment: you need to create your own `jquery` or `javascript` drop-down auto complete

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) it gives you what you have in your attached screenshot.

If you want a custom autocomplete (with tree structure) : you can use the [category](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) option in the jQuery autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.
This Will Create a list of the things you want to appear as suggestions .
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note :  The datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would want to use Ajax.
The way it works is as the user types, the ajax will send information the the server, telling it what the user has typed. The server will use this information to look up information from a data base. The server will then return the information from the database to the client. This information will be injected into the HTML drop-down.

You can find a detailed example of this here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp